# Android windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" scroll some more

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

Consider the following example for a view:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <EditText />
    <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in in the manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

onfocus edittext, the soft keyboard covers a button like so:

[image]

but I'd like it like this:

[image]

How to scroll view a little more so that the button is visible?

Comment: Please give the answer for this .

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft : just use `adjustResize` attribute

Comment: `adjustResize` may mess up with your layout in smaller screens

Answer (score 15):

I just found this post and saw it was unanswered. For the sake of helping others who may come 
use this in the manifest for activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```

try just one and see if that suits your needs.

Good luck

Comment: I must've tried 30 different combinations for windowSoftInputMode before finding this post. Thank you.

Comment: "stateUnchanged|adjustResize" will resize the window, and attempt to keep the currently focused item on screen. It will make no effort to keep the buttons on screen.

Comment: @DotProductSoft In which section of Manifest should be the property ?

Comment: Sorry. Only noticed your question today. You probably have found the answer, but  hopefully others can use this information. 
Put it in the manifest as an attribute of the <activity> tag that you are presenting.

Comment: How do you recreate this dynamically.I know this: getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN); But how do you tell it stateUnchanged?

Comment: KasparTr - Sorry I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: KasparTr - Try bitwise "OR" WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN

Answer (score -3):

Can you add an empty RelativeLayout below the buttons. 
set its android:layout_height="50dp" or any value that satisfy your need.
And use a ScrollView, notice that ScrollView can only have 1 child layout.

```
<ScrollView >
  <LinearLayout>
    <EditText />
    <Button />
    <RelativeLayout 
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```