# How to keep layout stable when using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm currently working on an Android App where there is a layout named "`add_expense.xml`", which gets triggered while using the Activity "`AddExpense.java`". In order to make the screen scrollable when the keyboard is active, I added the following line under the Activity in the Android Manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

However, the issue is that the layout file is long, and when the keyboard is activated, the layout automatically scrolls to the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to make it static so that the keyboard is activated AND the layout stays stable? It's quite annoying to have to scroll up to the top of the layout every time the keyboard is activated.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423459/android-windowsoftinputmode-adjustpan-scroll-some-more) that may be helpful

Comment: No, still does the same.

Comment: use scrollview to whole xml file