# Issue with Edittext and softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Having Problem with Edittext and SoftKeyboard.

[image: This is screen where hello is edittext]

now if i click on edittext(hello text) to modify it (means when it gains focus bottom gridview is poping up see second image)

[image]

so how to change this **behaviour of poping up the bottom views**?

Any Help will be greately appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deplicated Have a Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423459/android-windowsoftinputmode-adjustpan-scroll-some-more

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar thanks mate but i tried both but did not  worked for me.

Comment: Please Check This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you can open dialog and in dialog add EditText and on ok button you can change that text according to text added in dialog edittext.

Comment: there is no need dialog check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android

Answer (score 0):

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` property might be squeezing your background
use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
View activityRootView;

activityRootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root); // main layout id


activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                                .getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                        if (heightDiff > 100) {
                            // if more than 100 pixels, its

                            // hide your below layout like layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        } else {
                         // visible your below layout like layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }
                    }
                });
```